# Show message if all div are slide up on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="showmessage" style="display:none">you have removed all items</div>
  <div class=" col-sm-4"> data 1 <span class="close">close</span> </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-4"> data 2 </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-4"> data 3 </div>
</div>
<script>
$('.close').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.col-sm-4').slideUp();
});
</script>
```

I Want to show `.showmessage` when user hide all `.col-sm-4` one by one. 
Also, it should be shown after the sliding animation for the last item completes.

Comment: can you make jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('.close:visible').length === 0` to check if there are still any items open. Also, it seems like you forgot to add the other close buttons.

```js
$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.col-sm-4').slideUp(function() {
    if ($('.close:visible').length === 0) {
      $('.showmessage').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="showmessage" style="display:none">you have removed all items</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 1 <button class="close">close</button></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 2 <button class="close">close</button></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">data 3 <button class="close">close</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Nicolas McCurdy you made my dream come true :p :) thanks

Comment: I wouldnt show() all elements in the whole DOM with the class "showmessage" since you never know if there could be another one elsewhere :)

Comment: @Ferret you are right but i was working on the same code as Nicolas McCurdy clarify .. you solution is also good and i will definitely use that as well in future

Answer (score 1):

Check count of `.col-sm-4` when zero, use [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$('.close').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.col-sm-4').slideUp();
   if (!$('.col-sm-4').length) {
        $('.showmessage').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: The message is supposed to show only when all other divs are closed.

Comment: Also, you might want to put the if statement in a callback for `slideUp()` so it only runs after the sliding animation for the last item completes.

Comment: True, but I think it looks and feels a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bhxrq8z1/):

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.slideUp('fast', function () {
        if(!$(this).siblings('.col-sm-4').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings('.showmessage').show();
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.showmessage').hide();
        }
    });
});
```